# With gold and cash equal to nisab, but living in a rented house, is zakat wajib?

Tags: zakat

I have gold and cash equal to nisab e zakat but do not have a house and live in a rented house nor do I have enough money to purchase a house.

Is zakat wajib on me?

Comment: to live in a rented house has nothing to do with Zakat IMHO - being indebted would play a role... but in the situation you describe Zakat is obligatory AFAIK... Allah knows best.

Comment: Owning a house is a luxury, not a necessity. People have and are spending their lives in rented houses. Nisab for Zakat is a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you're renting a house or saving to buy a house is irrelevant; if your saved wealth has reached and maintained the nisab for a full year, zakat becomes incumbent on you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, zakaat is not payable on your personal house.   My case is:
Person 1: is living in a rental house and is saving to buy a new house.  The savings is in  bank  account bearing no interest and is above the nisab threshold.  He has to pay the zakaat.

Person 2: With his saving he has purchase a house for personal use.   He is not eligible for zakaat even if it is  a luxurious house.

Where  is the fairness in this?

Comment: This answer seems to be your best guess (first sentence), accompanied by a complaint about zakat (remainder of the answer).